# GeoServer Swedish characters doesn't work in legend

Tags: qgis, geoserver, internationalization

I have a GeoServer layer with Swedish characters (Å, Ä, Ö) in attributes table and legend. These do not work in QGIS legend.

How can I fix this?

The layer is originally a shapefile import to postgres via ogr2ogr. Accourding to the shapefile .cpg file the encoding is ISO 88591

The workspace charset is set to ISO-8859-1.

[image]

```
...
     <FeatureTypeStyle>
       <Rule>
         <Name>Fjällbjörkskog</Name>
         <ogc:Filter>
           <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
             <ogc:PropertyName>kkod</ogc:PropertyName>
             <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
           </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
         </ogc:Filter>
       <PolygonSymbolizer>
...
```

Comment: Looks like a bug - I'll investigate more and raise a ticket

Comment: I've created https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-10182